# identificar iframes con Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iframe

intento acceder al siguiente elemento:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual está dentro de un iframe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el Id del Iframa es dinámico, por lo que lo mande llamar con el div que se encuentra arriba del iframe:

divElement1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="hangout-landing-chat"]/iframe')
driver.switch_to_frame(divElement1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="eh XcEgrf fp pu hy"]').click()

pero no me funciona, ¿alguien tiene alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Puedes localizar el id  `hangout-landing-chat` y luego desde ese elemento  puedes localizar el iframe,  `find_element_by_tag_name('iframe') `.

Comment: pero el iframe es dinámico, siempre cambía su id y nombre